# VueTool Tip does not work in modal

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, tooltip, vue-component

I'm trying to use Vue ToolTip in my project. I can successfully get it to work on my page, however, it doesn't work on my modal pop up page.

I've created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bkw28n9h/

In this fiddle there is a `Tooltip` text on the page which shows up tooltip on hover. However, there is also a tool tip on the modal popup can comes up when clicking on any list item. The tooltip on the modal pop up does not show up on hover. Why is that?

I add the tooltip directive like this:

`Vue.use(vueDirectiveTooltip);`

Do I need to specifically add it to the modal component? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: have you seen my answer? I just want to know if it helped.

Comment: Yes it certainly did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your style this:

```
.h-tooltip {
   z-index: 99999!important;
}
```

The tooltip is being covered by your modal.